# Trying to find an old short story about two cats who are aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

In the early '70's I used to check out a book with short stories and one of them was about two cats that were actually alien spies, and they get found out when they get high on catnip.

Comment: Are you sure it was catnip and not anaesthetic? I seem to remember a similar story.

Comment: You're right and I found the book with the short story a few days ago ~ it's called "Some Are Born Cats" Thanks for responding!

Comment: @DrgnGrl64 so will you post this to the answer section ?